# Update user information and image through http request in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, httprequest

Good day,
I have a function in my Xamarin app where the user will click on after updating his information and image in order to change it in the server thorough http request. In my web API, the PUT function has following signature:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult UpdateUserInfo(int id, [FromForm] User user)
{
}
```

The image in the User class is of type iFromFile and in my Xamarin app I'm using MediaPicker to choose the image from the local storage. After updating the image and the user information, the following function is called to send the http request from Xamarin:

```
public static async Task<int> UpdateUserInformation(int UserId, UpdateUserInfo userInfo)
{
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userInfo);
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", Preferences.Get("accessToken", string.Empty));
var response = await httpClient.PutAsync(AppSettings.ApiUrl + "api/Accounts/UpdateUserInfo/" + UserId, content);
}
```

I'm getting the image from the device using below function and my question how can I pass the image as iFromFile in the UpdateUserInfo class before triggering above UpdateUserInformation function:

```
private async void updateUserImage_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
 {
                Title = "Choose image"

 });

    if (result != null)
            {
               var stream  = await result.OpenReadAsync();
                
           
           
                userImage.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
            }
        }
```

Your kind help is appreciated.

Comment: there are numerous existing questions on this topic: https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+iformfile+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thanks, i did check it out but my situation here is that i have the class UpdateUserInfo in Xamarin that has the property image with datatype iFromFile and i want to know how to pass the image from the device to UpdateUserInfo.image which then will be passed in the http request.

Comment: **IFormFile**, not **iFromFile**

Answer (score 0):

You can access file path like this:

```
var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
 {
   Title = "Choose image"
 });

if (result != null)
{
   var Source = result.Path;
   userImage.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile(Source);
}
```

HTTP REQUEST

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
 
  var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
  var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Source) // you can get it from the first code i wrote. var Source = result.Path;
  request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);

  var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
  var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

  
}
```

Comment: Dera Amjad, can you advise how i can take it from here and pass it in the http request method?

Comment: dear @AliAlfaraj if you want to send an image throw http request you send it in the request content as byt array.

Comment: dear @AliAlfaraj, i understand from your question that you want to send user information as json and image as byte array in the same request? if this what you mean then create a class with two properties ( userinfo and imagebytearray), create an instance of this object fill it with your info then serialize it to json and send it in the http req as json format. On you back end you then deserialize the json to the same object type to access both properties